# How to shrink int array basing on the number of elements?

Tags: c#

So let's say I have a base `int[] tab` array with 100 elements. I want to perform Erastotenes' Sieve using tmp array storing not compatibile elements. Since I don't know exactly how many elements will land in this array, I declare it as `new int[100]`. But is there any way to shrink that array after performing population task? Like for example, I end up with 46 numbers instead of 100, so I'd like to shrink that array's size accordingly, based on the number of said elements. I'd like to avoid manual resize, I'd rather do it programatically.

Sample code:

```
    int[] tab = new int[100];
    int[] tmp = new int[100];

    for(int i = 0; i < tab.Length; i++) {
        tab[i] = i;
    }
```

EDIT. One idea that came to my mind is to perform `while` loop strictly counting amount of elements in tmp array which could help me determine its final size.

EDIT 2. Working solution:

```
            int[] tab = new int[100];
            List<int> tmp = new List<int>();
            List<int> se = new List<int>();

            for(int i = 0; i < tab.Length; i++)
            {
                tab[i] = i + 2;
            }

            se.Add(tab[0]);
            se.Add(tab[1]);

            for (int i = 2; i < tab.Length; i++)
            {
                if (tab[i] % 2 == 0 || tab[i] % 3 == 0)
                {
                    if (tmp.IndexOf(tab[i]) == -1)
                    {
                        tmp.Add(tab[i]);
                    }
                }
            }

            int k = 3;
            int value;

            while(k < tab.Length)
            {
                if(tmp.IndexOf(tab[k]) == -1) {
                    value = tab[k];
                    for (int i = k; i < tab.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if(tmp.IndexOf(tab[i]) == -1)
                        {
                            if(tab[i] % value == 0 && tab[i] != value)
                            {
                                tmp.Add(tab[i]);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if(se.IndexOf(tab[i]) == -1)
                                {
                                    se.Add(tab[i]);
                                }
                            }
                        } 
                    }
                }
                k++;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Zawartość tablicy początkowej:");
            for(int i = 0; i < tab.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(tab[i] + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Elementy wykluczone:");
            foreach(int t in tmp)
            {
                Console.Write(t + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Sito Erastotenesa:");
            foreach (int s in se)
            {
                Console.Write(s + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
```

Comment: Just use a List<> instead of an Array and use tab.Add(i);

Comment: yeah, I saw this kind of solution somewhere else, but I wanted to figure it out with standard int array.

Comment: Do you know the index of the last valued element of the array?

Comment: @Steve unfortunately no, because it all depends on the content from tab array. I'd have to loop through it.

Comment: So how can you differentiate when an element of the original array has not been changed from your code? I mean the default value  for an int is zero. Is zero an acceptable outcome from your algorithm that fills the array?

Comment: @Steve oops, my mistake - I should have used tab[i] = i + 2 instead, since I want to fill the array with values starting from 2. The main idea was to identify elements not eligible for the algorithm, populate tmp array with them, and in the end loop through base array once more and check if current element is not present in tmp array. If not, pick it as one of GCDs. This solution is far from being optimal, but it's not my call since it's for my classes and teacher wants this specific approach to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't shrink an array (or grow, for that matter). You can create a *new* array with the correct size and copy the data to the new one, but an array, once created, can not change size.

The easiest way to achieve this is using `List<T>` which is nothing more than a thin wrapper over an array that hides away all the plumbing of how and when the underlying array needs to grow and copying data from the "depleted" to the newer array.

Once you've populated the list, if you need an array then simply call `ToArray()`.

Comment: maybe it's just my old habits from C++, where it was actually possible to resize arrays. well, in that case I'd have to do it according to your suggestion. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Resize<T> (ref T[]? array, int newSize);
```

This method allocates a new array with the specified size, copies elements from the old array to the new one, and then replace the old array with the new one. the array must be a one-dimensional array.
Changes the number of elements of a one-dimensional array to the specified new size.

You can [read the full article here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.resize)

Comment: thanks, but I don't want to use built-in C# methods, I want to figure out my own solution to this problem.

Comment: How about just creating a new array after you know the size?

Comment: Do bear in mind that in reality `Resize` does not resize the original array. It simply creates a new one with the new size and copies that relevant data from one to another.

Comment: yeah, I know. Everything clicked after you mentioned that arrays cannot be modified in C# after declaration.